# remove 'mailto:' from selenium get_attribute('href')

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, mailto

I'm scraping a site and am able to pull down an email href attribute but all of the emails contain the mailto: tag. For example, I'd like the email mailto:john@gmail.com to just be john@gmail.com. I've searched stack and am finding several regular expression solutions but am unable to implement them. In Python 3.6 the import re stays gray. It seems like that must be a default library now but it isn't working. I've also tried altering the XPATH but am unclear on how to render the XPATH since Selenium doesn't allow you to do that apparently.

Here is my code:

```
try:
    element = "//div[@class='business-buttons']/a[1]"
    email_el = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, element)
    email = email_el.get_attribute("href")
 except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Handled NoSuchElementException no email")
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the method [.replace()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm):

```
email.replace("mailto:", "")
```

If you have a list of scraped emails you can use `.replace()` in a loop:

```
email_list = ['mailto:john@gmail.com','mailto:john2@gmail.com','mailto:john3@gmail.com']
for item in email_list:
    item = item.replace("mailto:", "")
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
john@gmail.com
john2@gmail.com
john3@gmail.com
```

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks very much for your kind comment and up-vote! I appreciate it.